# Undefined Variable + function not returning variable

Tags: php

Okay so here's my code:

```
function payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime, $paycheck) {
if ($hours <= 40) {
    $paycheck = $hours * $wage;
}
else {
    $paycheck = $hours * $overtime;
}
return $paycheck;

}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$wage = $_POST['wage'];

$paycheck = payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime, $paycheck);

$overTime = $wage * 1.5;
print "Your paycheck for this period is:"; 
print $paycheck; 
print ".";
```

The problem is I keep getting undefined variable errors on $paycheck. As far as I know, I have the if/else set up properly, but it's not returning `$paycheck`. Which means that on the "`print $paycheck;`" line, it's not able to print. What am I missing?

EDIT: There IS more to this, but it's just echo lines to spit out the `$name` and `$dept` variables.

Comment: $hours, $wage and $overtime don't exist within the scope of your function - pass them as arguments; nor are you calling the payCalc() function anywhere; and in that function, you're not doing anything to update the value of $paycheck

Comment: you don't seem to be calling the `payCalc()` function anywhere?

Comment: Read [PHP: Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) - functions don't close over variables like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare

```
$paycheck = payCalc();
```

so that you get the result coming from the function.

Also take in consideration:

```
if ($hours <= 40) {
    $paycheck = $hours * $wage;
}
else {
    $paycheck = $hours * $overtime;
```

that is, populate $paycheck.

And finally, take into account what has been advised by other users: if you want to use external variables, you need to send them to the function:

```
function payCall($hours, $wage, $overtime) {
   ...
}
```

and then use them when calling the function:

```
$paycheck = payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime);
```

Comment: I did all that and now I'm getting 'undefined index' and 'undefined variable' errors for all of my variables.

Comment: Please update your code in the question so we can review what can be wrong now.

Comment: OK @user2082686, what you have to do is to define the function previously to calling it. That is, all the block starting on `function payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime, $paycheck) {` and finishing in `return $paycheck; }` has to be moved to the top of the file.

Comment: Did that. Updated code at the top. Same errors. Undefined index error on $name, $dept, $hours, $wage and undefined variable for $overtime and $paycheck.

Comment: Also, `$paycheck` is returning now at the bottom (with the `print` line) but as 0. @fedorqui

Comment: You do not need to send $paycheck to the function, just use three variables: `function payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime) {`. Also, you define `$overTime = $wage * 1.5;` after `$paycheck = payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime, $paycheck);`. Swap lines. Finally, `$name = $_POST['name'];` and other variables are coming from $_POST, they have to come from a form.

Comment: I got it! Thank you! This has been an important lesson for me in the importance of what order things are in. @fedorqui

Comment: Haha, you are welcome @user2082686. Best wishes for your PHP learning! : ) If it worked, you can mark this answer's question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In a function, you cannot call variables from outside it.

There's no way your function knows `$paycheck.`

do it like this:

```
function payCall($hours, $wage, $overtime, $paycheck) {
 //DO STUFF
return $paycheck;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
echo payCall($hours, $wage, $overtime, $paycheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['dept']) && isset($_POST['hours']) && isset($_POST['wage']){
    $paycheck = '';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $dept = $_POST['dept'];
    $hours = $_POST['hours'];
    $wage = $_POST['wage'];

    $overTime = $wage * 1.5;

    function payCalc() {
        if ($hours <= 40) {
        $paycheck =$hours * $wage;
    }
    else {
        $paycheck = $hours * $overtime;
    }
    return $paycheck;
}

print "Your paycheck for this period is:"; 
print payCalc(); 
print ".";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't really set the variable "paycheck" in your function.

Set the variable $paycheck before your $hours * $overtime and $hours * $wage.

However, before being able to access those, you have to set them as parameters.

The code should then be something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$wage = $_POST['wage'];

$overTime = $wage * 1.5;

function payCalc($hours, $wage, $overtime) {
    if ($hours <= 40) {
        $paycheck = $hours * $wage;
    }
    else {
        $paycheck = $hours * $overtime;
    }
    return $paycheck;
}

print "Your paycheck for this period is:"; 
print payCalc($hours, $wage, $overTime); 
print ".";
```

The function now returns the variable "paycheck", which is set within the if-statement and the else-statement.

Does this make any sense to you?

Best,

Nikolaj Jepsen

Answer (score 0):

```
/// COPY AND PASTE THE BELOW CODE

$paycheck = '';

$name = $_POST['name'];

$dept = $_POST['dept'];

$hours = $_POST['hours'];

$wage = $_POST['wage'];

$overTime = $wage * 1.5;

function payCalc($paycheck,$hours,$wage,$overTime) {

    if ($hours <= 40) {

       $paycheck = $hours * $wage;

    }

    else {

       $paycheck =  $hours * $overTime;

    }

    return $paycheck;

}


print "Your paycheck for this period is:"; 

print payCalc($paycheck,$hours,$wage,$overTime); 

print ".";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using global keyword.

```
$paycheck = '';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$wage = $_POST['wage'];

$overTime = $wage * 1.5;

function payCalc() {
    global $hours,$wage,$overtime,$paycheck;
    if ($hours <= 40) {
        $hours * $wage;
    }
    else {
        $hours * $overtime;
    }
    return $paycheck;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **global** keyword to refer to global variables :

```
$paycheck = '';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$wage = $_POST['wage'];

$overTime = $wage * 1.5;

function payCalc() {
    global $hours, $wage, $overtime;
    $paycheck = 0;
    if ($hours <= 40) {
        $paycheck = $hours * $wage;
    }
    else {
        $paycheck = $hours * $overtime;
    }
    return $paycheck;
}


$paycheck = payCalc();
print "Your paycheck for this period is:"; 
print $paycheck; 
print ".";
```

Comment: This is clearly a new user of PHP - let's not advise such bad practise from the start.

Comment: @cbuckley I am indeed new to this. I wouldn't know how to handle global variables at this point and I'd rather learn what's wrong (which I am through reading all this) rather than just put that (global) in without knowing what it does.